# How to run GUI script automatically after logged in to desktop window in rasberry pi

Tags: python, putty, raspberry-pi, gui

I'm using raspberry pi 3 and i have made gui script with two button and one image, it is running well if we run using command:

```
sudo python
sudo python gui.py
```

But i want to automatic run this gui script after i am logged in to raspberry pi desktop window. I don't know how to do this? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create in home directory folders `~/.config/autostart` by running following command:

`mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart`

and create inside of this directory text file `mygui.desktop`

`touch ~/.config/autostart/mygui.desktop`

then add to this file description of your program, something like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyGUI
Exec=/usr/bin/python gui.py
Type=Application
Hidden=false
```

More on creating `.desktop` file [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

If you really need to run GUI program as `root` (???) then you need to use desktop's replacement of `sudo`, it is `gksu`